# How to make conditional import work in React JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have three pages in my react website that have the same layout and different content. I've made an array within a js file to map through the content, but I don't want to duplicate my code to another component.

The point is the I need the variable name to be the same, so I can map it.

I can get what I need with require matching the page url, but since I read it's not a good practice in react due to performance issues, I'm trying to accomplish it with import with no sucess though.

```
let pagedata = [];
if (matchpage1) {
    pagedata = require("./data").page1data;
} else if (matchpage2) {
    pagedata = require("./data").page2data;
} else if (matchpage3) {
    pagedata = require("./data").page3data;
}

return (

pagedata.map((item) => {
```

I've read the react documentation, searched a lot, tried a lot of code, but nothing works if I try a simiçar aproach with import and lazy.

```
let pagedata = [];
if (matchpage1) {
    pagedata = React.lazy(() => import('./pagedata1'));
} else if (matchpage2) {
    pagedata = React.lazy(() => import('./pagedata2'));
} else if (matchpage3) {
   pagedata = React.lazy(() => import('./pagedata3'));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: add `await` before `import("./file_path)`

Comment: I think your problem is that you arent using useState to set the data of page content... trying changing your let variable to a useState, so react can knows theres a update in the mapped variable and rerender the DOM

Comment: @simpa, can you give me an example of how to do this? I'm used to use "useState" on clicks ```const test [testdata, settestdata] = usestate(false) ```;   but I didn't get what you told me to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Anilkumar, I'll try. Thabk you so much.